# How to get extension version

Tags: angular, typescript

How I can get extension version from chrome in my TS code Angular 9.Thnx.

I I have tried several options

```
`chrome.getExtension('knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik')`
```

but I have errors on
chrome...() is not a function. Help please.

Comment: You want to get extension version from the website? Is this your extension?

Comment: It`s my extension. It located in chrome where is all extensions, top right of chrome, under puzzle icon.

Comment: If you have version saved in your extension you could use content script to inject extension version into window. You can access that easily on the website.

Comment: @
Bojan Kogoj
One working example? I receive only: null, undefined or chrome....() is not a function